# A question on the electromagnetic field tensor

Tags: electromagnetism, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, variational-calculus

Consider

\begin{equation}
\delta \left(F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}\right)=2F^{\mu\nu}\delta F_{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}

I am trying to convince myself that the above holds for any arbitrary explicit form of $F_{\mu\nu}$. I was able to see that the equation holds in cartesian coordinates by explicitly writing it out. However, I don't think it is sufficient to say that since the equation holds in cartesian coordinates, the equation is then true for any coordinates. Moreover, the metric tensor need not be diagonal so the components of the transformed rank 2 tensor might not contain terms present in the respective components of the original tensor.

Is there a proper and easy to understand explanation to why the equation is always true, which can also be applied to other objects such as $\partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\delta$ commutes with metric tensors in addition to obeying the Leibniz rule,$$\begin{align}\delta(F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu})&=g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\sigma}\delta(F_{\rho\sigma}F_{\mu\nu})\\&=g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\sigma}\delta F_{\rho\sigma}F_{\mu\nu}+g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\sigma}F_{\rho\sigma}\delta F_{\mu\nu}\\&= \delta F_{\rho\sigma}F^{\rho\sigma}+F^{\mu\nu}\delta F_{\mu\nu}\\&= \delta F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+F^{\mu\nu}\delta F_{\mu\nu},\end{align}$$where in the last line we relabel indices in one term. Note to get this as $2F^{\mu\nu}\delta F_{\mu\nu}$ we technically also need commutativity (for example, you won't get the result you requested if $F$ is Grassmann-valued.) You're welcome to repeat this in the much simpler case of $\delta(\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi)$ as an exercise.